# ls command still reads the default configuration even after setting the LS_COLORS

Tags: linux, bash, ls, colors

I know there are several related questions asked about this but I could't solve my problem with those.

**Expected behavior**:
What I want is to disable all coloring stuff and just make the directories magenta. In other words : `--color=never` + magenta directories.

**Current behavior**:
`ls` already reads my `LS_COLORS` environment variable **but** I also see the green background for directories too. It seems like the `LS_COLORS` is just an override to the default coloring.

**What I've done so far**:

1. I edited my `~/.bashrc` file, set the `LS_COLORS` manually and `export`ed it.
2. I noticed that there is a section in this file that tries to run `dircolors` program so that it [sets the `LS_COLORS`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html). But since I'm doing it myself I commented it out:

```bash
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases                               
#if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then                                                   
#    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolor> 
#    alias ls='ls --color=auto'                                                       
#    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'                                                    
#    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'                                                  
#                                                                                     
#    alias grep='grep --color=auto'                                                   
#    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'                                                 
#    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'                                                 
#fi
```

3. This is how I set it:

```bash
LS_COLORS='di=01;35'; export LS_COLORS                                                
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Again, the above line works. If I change `35` to `34` I would see the difference.

But what is annoying is I only want this color and nothing else:

[image]

Isn't `ls` supposed to only read this variable for coloring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` has default colours for several file types, and all of them need to be overridden if you don’t want them to be applied.

In your case,

```
eval $(dircolors -p | awk '/^TERM/ { print; next } /^[A-Z]/ { $2 = "00" } /^DIR/ { $2 = "01;35" } /^\./ { next } 1' | dircolors -)
```

will clear all the defaults and set the colour for directories.

Comment: I see. I thought `ls` would get its information only from `LS_COLORS` but it turns out that it's mostly for overridden. I replaced my single `''di=01;35''` with the result of this and it works like a charm. Thanks.